# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my code

```
 const Res = await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json`);
        const ResObj = await Res.json();
        if (!Res.ok || !ResObj) { 
          throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
        } 
        const ResArr = await Object.values(ResObj)
            .map(v => Object.values(v).flat())//error
            .flat()
            .filter(({ title }) => title.includes(Search))
```

In the line In the line I get this error ".map (v => Object.values (v) .flat ())" I get this error Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Well, you haven't defined any types here, i'd start with that :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to help TypeScript understand the types of the objects you're dealing with.  The `fetch` API can't know in advance what the shape of the returned objects are going to be, so you have to define it and assert that the results conform to it.

Looking at what's at https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
interface ResObj {
  Mens: {
    Hat: Clothing[];
    Jacket: Clothing[];
    Pants: Clothing[];
    Shoes: Clothing[];
    Suit: Clothing[];
  };
  New: Clothing[];
}
interface Clothing {
  agility: boolean[];
  alt: string;
  color: string[][];
  id: string;
  location?: string; // fix this
  Location?: string; // fix this
  material: string;
  price: string[][];
  prodState: string;
  saiz: string[][];
  shipping: string;
  sold: string;
  src: string[][];
  title: string;
  to: string;
}
```

But of course whether or not that's accurate depends on some kind of API documentation.  Assuming that's right, you can go a bit further:

```
  const Res = await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json`);
  const ResObj: ResObj | undefined = await Res.json();
  if (!Res.ok || !ResObj) {
    throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
  }
```

Now `ResObj` will be known as type `ResObj` and you can start manipulating it.  One issue is that the standard library's typings for [`Object.values()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L22-L32) and [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L152-L223) don't reflect what you're doing with them.  We can build some custom typings for them... but in this case I'll just wrap them with new functions whose types match:

```
  // return an array of all object values...
  // if the object is already an array, the output is the same type.
  // otherwise it's the union of all the known property types
  function vals<T extends object>(
    arr: T
  ): Array<T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T[keyof T]> {
    return Object.values(arr); // need es2017 lib for this
  }

  // Flatten an array by one level... 
  function flat<T>(
    arr: Array<T>
  ): Array<Extract<T, any[]>[number] | Exclude<T, any[]>> {
    return arr.flat(); // need esnext lib for this
  }
```

Those functions typings might be confusing if you've never used TypeScript before, especially since they rely on [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) to tease out the array properties.

Then we can rewrite your code like this:

```
  const ResArr = flat(vals(ResObj).map(v => flat(vals(v)))).filter(
    ({ title }) => title.includes(Search)
  );
```

And there are no errors, and the compiler understands that `ResArr` is an array of `Clothing` objects.

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4HkBGArZAbwChlkBZCEDALiNLOQAk4w6BhAGwHswALUAHMA2gF0A3AzIApRAGsIbZF14CQIiVOQAFOOFrKe-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)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: holy shuh that function typing... so sick

Answer (score 14):

#### Problem

`Res.json()` returns a value of type `any`, and when `Object.values` receives input of type `any`, it returns an `unknown[]`. When `strictNullChecks` is on, TypeScript will not let us assign a value of type `unknown` to a parameter of type `{}`.

That explanation is also inline with the comments.

```
const func = async () => {

    const Res = await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json`);

    /**
     * The ResObj is that `Res.json()` returns is of type `any`.
     */
    const ResObj = await Res.json();

    if (!Res.ok || !ResObj) {
        throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
    }

    /**
     * When we pass Object.values a type of `any`, 
     * it produces an array of type `unknown[]`.
     */
    const unknownArray = Object.values(ResObj);

    /**
     * `Object.values` has two signatures: 
     * 
     * * `values(o: {}): any[];`
     * * `values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } |  ArrayLike<T>): T[];`
     * 
    * When `strictNullCheck` is `true`, we cannot assign `unknown` to `{}`.
    */
    const ResArr = unknownArray.map(unknownItem => Object.values(unknownItem));
};
```

#### Two Possible Solutions

1. Disable `strictNullChecks` (not recommended).
2. Add a type to the `ResObj`.

The latter option looks like this:

```
type MyKnownType = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    prop3: boolean;
};

const ResObj: MyKnownType = await Res.json();
```

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions I've found are:

### 1. Use a type assertion

Using the `as` syntax:

```
const Res = await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json`);
const ResObj = (await Res.json()) as ResObj;
```

Or the angle bracket syntax:

```
const Res = await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json`);
const ResObj = <ResObj>(await Res.json());
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

### 2 - Disable strictNullChecks (not recommended)

This is not recommended because it can result in unexpected errors during runtime.

Edit your `tsconfig.json` and set this property like so:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
...
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

### Other Notes

An approach that did not work for me was using the variable type like so:

```
const Res = await fetch(`https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/.json`);
const ResObj: ResObj = await Res.json();
```

If I did this I would get the error "Type `unknown` is not assignable to type `ResObj`. TS2322"

There is discussion about making fetch's `json` method better typing here: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1262