# How to generate array of object from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
{
   name: 'ABC',
   age: 12,
   timing: '2021-12-30T11:12:34.033Z'
}
```

I want to make array of object of each key of above object like this:

```
[
   {
      fieldName: 'name',
      dataType: 'string'
   },
   {
      fieldName: 'age',
      dataType: 'number'
   },
   {
      fieldName: 'timing',
      dataType: 'date'
   }
]
```

I tried this:

```
let op = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
            fieldName: key,
            dataType: typeof value
        }));
```

but getting dataType: 'object' for date column
but not able to achieve it. Is there any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yah it's working with it. but not able to do it for dataType key, because it is not working for date type

Comment: Declare your Object like this `{ fieldName: key, dataType: typeof value}`

Comment: @SaschaLeh I did the same thing, but I got result as "object" for date column

Comment: As a eager as I am too to close this question, I'm voting to re-open citing OPs last comment. There is a special case where the string `date` has to be used if the value of the property is a valid time stamp.

Comment: do you have always an iso date string as date type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use date parse to check is a valid date or not.

```js
const input = {
  name: 'ABC',
  age: 12,
  timing: '2021-12-30T11:12:34.033Z'
};

const output = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => ({
  fieldName: key,
  dataType: typeof value === 'string' && !isNaN(Date.parse(value)) ?  'date':typeof value
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: fieldName should be the object key, not it's value ;(

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to the get the type of the value. For the case where `'date'` must be used for valid time stamps, you could use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method with [`Number#isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

Try the following

```js
const input = {
  name: 'ABC',
  age: 12,
  timing: '2021-12-30T11:12:34.033Z'
};

const output = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => ({
  fieldName: key,
  dataType: typeof value !== 'string' || isNaN(Date.parse(value)) ? typeof value : 'date'
}));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Edit: Replace `Object#values` with `Object#entries`.

Edit 2: Add `typeof value !== 'string'` for `dataType` condition. Borrowed from @RahulSharma's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70875785/6513921).

Comment: getting error: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: @techguy: Update the question with your attempt. Obviously there is an error in the types you're using.

Comment: now it's not working with numbers, it showing 'date' for number columns as well

Comment: for age column also it showing 'date'

Comment: @techguy: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487020/6513921) for the `unknown` error. TL;DR: Try to define a type for the input. If you get the "_Type `'number'` is not assignable to type `'string'`_" error for `Date.parse()`, include a type check for `'string'` as shown by @RahulSharma in his answer.

Comment: @techguy: The solution is working in the inline code. If you get `'date'` for all the properties of the object, please try to create a reproducible example.

Comment: you can see your own example's output by clicking on button "Run code snippet", for age column it is 'date'

Comment: Unfortunately we're still running into browser issues. It's returning `'number'` in Firefox, and `'date'` in Chrome. I'll update the post to borrow from @RahulSharma's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
const ip = {
  name: 'ABC',
  age: 12,
  timing: '2021-12-30T11:12:34.033Z'
};

const op = Object.keys(ip).map((key) => ({
  fieldName: key,
  dataType: typeof ip[key] === 'string' && !isNaN(Date.parse(ip[key])) ? 'date' : typeof ip[key]
}));

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks fine, you just need to distinguish between normal `string` and a valid `date` string.

For this, I would recommend using [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) package.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const input = {
  name: "ABC",
  age: 12,
  timing: "2021-12-30T11:12:34.033Z"
};

const output = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => {
  return {
    fieldName: key,
    dataType:
      typeof value === "string"
        ? dayjs(value).isValid()
          ? "date"
          : "string"
        : typeof value
  };
});

console.log("output", output);
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-swirles-4if50?file=/src/index.js:0-385)

If you want to reinvent the wheel and write a date checking function yourself, then take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value) for a few suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => (
{
    fieldName: key,
    dataType: isNaN(value) && !isNaN(Date.parse(value)) ? 'date' : typeof(value) 
}))
```

But be careful with this as it will return for invalid dates in February, rg: 2013-02-31

With the date checking, you may should use some libraries such as Momentjs, . .