# Typescript: Switching from axios to fetch is giving a type error

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am having an issue switching from Axios to Fetch in the expected types being returned.  My original code with Axios is as follows:

```
private async getAccessType(): Promise<string> {
    const config: RequestInit = {
        method: "get",
        baseURL: SERVER_INFO.URL,
        url: '/getData',
        headers: {
            Authorization: this.token,
            "X-Api-key": SERVER.KEY
        }
    };


    const response = await axios(config);
    const { library } = await response.data;

    return library;  // result is "access" or "no-access"
}
```

The result of the response is JSON:

```
{ 
  "library": "access",
  "name": {
     "first": "James"
  }
}
```

so I am just destructuring it and returning `library` in the function, which is a `string`.

I am trying to switch to `fetch` now:

```
import fetch, { RequestInit } from "node-fetch";


private async getAccessType(): Promise<string> {
    const baseURL: SERVER_INFO.URL;

    const config: RequestInit = {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            Authorization: this.token,
            "X-Api-key": SERVER.KEY
        }
    };


    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/getData`,config);
    const { library } = await response.json();  

    return library;  
}
```

and the line `const { library } = await response.data;`   is giving me a TS error of
`Property 'library' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Comment: did you try let library = await response.data

Comment: or something like let library = []any = await response.data;

assuming its an array coming back

Comment: This question is similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/56485202/990642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch.json()` returns a `Promise<unknown>`, TypeScript doesn't let you grab a property of `unknown` because it doesn't know if it exists on the response object, hence the error.

> Property 'library' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

You could cast your response to what you expect from the request.

```
const { library } = await data.json() as { library: string };
```

In your case, you could create an `interface` for the expected response.

```
// expected response
interface IFetchRes {
  library: string;
  name: {
    first: string;
  }
}

// unknown => interpret as expected response
const { library, name } = await data.json() as IFetchRes;
```